# Net5.0 Razor Pages CRUD Delete Error, Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I keep getting this error when I try deleting an album:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(int rc, sqlite3 db)

DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

This is the Delete.cshtml.cs Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ChinookApp.Models;

namespace ChinookApp.Pages_Albums
{
    public class DeleteModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ChinookAppContext _context;

        public DeleteModel(ChinookAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Album Album { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Album = await _context.albums.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlbumId == id);

            if (Album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Album = await _context.albums.FindAsync(id);

            if (Album != null)
            {
                _context.albums.Remove(Album);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Delete.cshtml Page:

```
@page
@model ChinookApp.Pages_Albums.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Album</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Album.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.Title)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p><h4>Related Tracks</h4></p>
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Track[0].TrackId)
            </th>        
            <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Track[0].Name)
            </th>  
            <th></th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>    
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Album.tracks) {
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TrackId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

        </tr>
    
}
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Album.AlbumId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

My Album Model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ChinookApp.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Track> tracks { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Artist> artists { get; set; }

        }
}
```

Comment: it seems like you have data that references the album you are trying to delete. You can handle this many ways. You can delete everything referencing it first. Or you can set the cascade behavior to update the referencing item to null album id. Those are probably the two most commonly used options.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Album has two one-to-many associated attributes. When you delete Album, its associated attributes are not deleted, which leads to foreign key constraint problems, like
@Crowcoder said, you have two solutions.

One way you can change your code like below:

```
  Album = await _context.albums.Where(c=>c.Id==id).Include(c=>c.tracks).Include(c=>c.artists).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The second way is use `Fluent API` OnDelete Method:

For the details you can see:

Doc : [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete).

Article:[The Fluent API OnDelete Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method).